# I'm looking for a word that's like a whimsical fanatic someone who dives in to something for a period of time and then moves on

Tags: word-choice

For example a person might be really into soccer so they do a bunch of soccer until hey get bored, but then they move to carpentry and get pretty good at that and know everything then they move on I, need a good word or phrase to describe this ferocious nomadic interest acquiring.

Comment: I'd like to call him a "mercurial enthusiast' ,  but I'm not sure that would get the point across standing on it's own

Comment: Are you saying they master each skill completely and then move on or they just show a lot of interest, buy equipment, do it for a bit until something new catches their attention?  Is this trait a good thing or a bad thing?

Comment: possibly dilettante

Comment: @Jim I think "get pretty good at that and know everything then they move on" is at least a professional capacity if not a masterful one.

Answer (score 2):

Try 'dilettante' or 'dabbler'. However, you might want to look at the symptoms of ADHD to see if they are relevant in this case.